# jQuery cycle pager scrollTop

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I have this:

```
<div id="slides">
    <img src="images/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/5.jpg">
</div>

<div id="t-container">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li><img src="images/1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/4.jpg"></li>
        <li id="lasty"><img src="images/5.jpg"></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

and my javascript code is:

```
        $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('#slides').cycle({
                fx: 'scrollLeft',
                pager: 'ul.thumbs',
                pagerAnchorBuilder: function(index, el) {
                    return '';
                },

                before: function() {
                    if ($('#lasty .activeSlide').length > 0) {
                        $('.thumbs').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('.thumbs').scrollTop() + 100
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    );
```

I am searching Google for the last 2 days and cannot arrive to any solution.

What i need is to animate last child of the `li` to scroll up with animation 100px when it gets the `class=activeSlide`. Because I have the height set so that the thumbnail image container does not show the last slide, and it is hidden.

I need that when the last `li` it gets the `activeSlide` it should move up to visible area as it is hidden by 'overflow: hidden' property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used the wrong selector here `$('#lasty .activeSlide')`

If the last `li` will get the class `.activeSlide`, the selector should be `$('#lasty.activeSlide')`

Also use can use the `.hasClass()` to simplify the logic

`if($('#lasty').hasClass('activeSlide'))`

See if this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but the hasClass does not help. Also'if' gets executed one time.i need a solution that runs in endless loop.

Comment: Try using `onPrevNextEvent` event instead of  `before`. [Source](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)